# Surrogate VS Primary Key Identifier

Tags: primary-key

If you didn't have a surrogate key how would you create a second row if the primary identifier has already in use?  What should happen if the row with the primary identifier is later deleted?

Comment: Please provide a code sample to compliment your question.

Comment: You must have something to uniquely and reliably identify each row of data - a **primary key**. Whether that's a surrogate column or not doesn't matter; if you don't (want to) have a surrogate, you'll need to find a "real" data column (or combination of real data columns) that can serve as the primary key (that will be unique for each row, non-null and preferably non changing).

Answer (score 0):

The question does not help. Whether a row has a surrogate key or not does solve the problem. A primary key is unique, by definition.

The scenario you describe has column values that are clearly not keys, as they are duplicated.

If you need to use these as the basis of a key, concatenate them with another column, possibly even just a sequentially increasing serial number.

Comment: But what will happen if the row with the primary identifier is later deleted?

Comment: The primary key is constructed from one or more concatenated columns. The value of the key in each row is unique. The key in each row is independent of every other row. Your business rules may be invalidated if you delete some specific rows, but the referential integrity will be the same. Maybe you need to have an additional table that contains only a fragment as the primary key, and reference this in your main table. Read up on compound keys and referential integrity.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary key is not a surrogate key, then your primary key is called a natural key. A natural key may be single column, if the natural key is composed of multiple columns then it's called compound key. All keys had to be unique, if you have a business rule whereby you want to create another row if the key already exists, then your "key" would not be unique, and that set of columns cannot and shouldn't be used as a key. The database will produce an error of you try to INSERT a route violating unique/key constraint.